# Add existing production files to new Git repository

Tags: git

I'm new to Git so please be gentle :) I'm trying to setup a workflow based on [this guide](https://gist.github.com/mediabeastnz/4f6254d3d8df37de218f) by mediabeastnz, however I need to do this on a website that has been live for some time without any repos. I followed all the steps (hopefully correctly) and I'm at a point where if I understand correctly, I need to "add" all the production files to the repository, then somehow cause the Staging folder to be synced with the Production one, etc.

My current setup is as follows:

- Live production files inside ~/www/ (public facing)
- Staging files inside ~/svn/(this is pre-existing so can't rename it)
- Inside ~/ (outside the public folder) I have now created 3 repositories: 1 global to track changes, 1 for production and one for staging, with hooks to keep things in sync.

In the guide on step 14, the author says: "This hook tells the repo to automatically pull and checkout the latest version of your website in the dev folder". I just don't know how to trigger this action so that staging is up to date, and whether there are other steps I need to take before this.

Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to add details or clarify anything. I wasn't sure how much detail to include. Also I might be misunderstanding the way this works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post-receive` is a server side hook that will run automagically ["...These scripts run before and after pushes to the server..."](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#__code_post_receive_code)

The [document you linked](https://gist.github.com/mediabeastnz/4f6254d3d8df37de218f) described a bit further down how this hook falls into the flow:

> Now lets say I want those new files pushed to the staging (dev.apple.com) repo, id' run this:
>
> 1. $ git push staging master
>
> The hook we setup will now be initiated and will automatically checkout...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had assumed this meant pushing "new" files from my local machine onto the Staging environment, rather than pushing all the "live" files onto Staging. Do the 3 terms push/staging/master mean that it grabs the master (which I assume are the live website files) and copies them into the Staging directory? Or am I reading this all wrong again?

Comment: Whenever you make changes to existing files or add new ones you will check them into `master` into your private local repo. You will then push them to the remote private repo(steps 1-3 in workflow). From there you want them to go to staging so you follow step 4 in the workflow. The changes you pushed to master in steps 1-3 are now in staging(dev.apple.com). Step 5 in workflow takes the same set of changes you pushed to master in steps 1-3 and makes them available in production(apple.com)

Comment: Thanks again. I think the whole setup process I followed was missing a key step. The problem is that I do not have any of these files on my local machine. The setup existed before I took over so the step I believe I'm missing are these:

Comment: Thanks again for your patience. I think the whole setup process I followed was missing a key step, since I'm not starting a new project from scratch. I do not have any of these files on my local machine yet. The setup existed before I took over so the steps I believe I'm missing are these: Turn the existing live website into a Git "powered" website. Turn the existing Staging into something that is linked/in sync with the live website. Pull the files into my local machine from the newly created repos. Then figure out the process to start making changes, push them to staging then to production.